# Update multiple rows in single select

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

I'm getting multiple rows in single select error with this SQL:

```
UPDATE ITEMS IT  
SET IT.BCOST = (SELECT V.PRICE + (V.PRICE * 0.1) 
                FROM VENDOR V
                WHERE V.ITEMNO = IT.ITEMNO)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM VENDOR V WHERE V.ITEMNO = IT.ITEMNO)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is itemno a primary key for the vendor table? Or at least a unique, not null column? From what I would infer from the code given, itemno is unique for items, but not vendor. It looks like a column in vendor that would reference the primary key in items.

Comment: Thank you Penguin359  ItemNo is Key Field in Irtems Table , Itemno is one of the key fields in Vendor Table ( Vendor Keys = ItemNo, CustNo)

Comment: I think the problem you have is that multiple vendor records will reference the same item, potentially. However, I don't understand your statement about multiple key fields in the vendor table. Do you mean that ItemNo and CustNo are Foreign keys to other tables? If you get back multiple entries in the vendors table, how to you want to combine them? Do you want to sum them up?

Comment: Thank you so much Penguin359   I just noticed that Vendor table could have 1 than more vendors (CustNo)  for a same ItemNo so i changed my Sql like below    UPDATE ITEMS IT  SET IT.BCOST=(SELECT V.PRICE + (V.PRICE * 0.1) FROM VENDOR V
WHERE V.ITEMNO=IT.ITEMNO)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM VENDOR V WHERE V.ITEMNO=IT.ITEMNO)

Comment: I couldnt edit my prior post, my post should have been like below                   Thank you so much Penguin359   I just noticed that Vendor table could have 1 than more vendors (CustNo)  for a same ItemNo so i changed my Sql and added another field with unique to get just 1 record for 1 item and now it works    UPDATE ITEMS IT  SET IT.BCOST=(SELECT V.PRICE + (V.PRICE * 0.1) FROM VENDOR V WHERE V.PREFERRED = 'Yes' and V.ITEMNO=IT.ITEMNO)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM VENDOR V WHERE V.ITEMNO=IT.ITEMNO and V.PREFERRED = 'Yes')   Thank You So Much

Comment: Please provide a [mre], and add information by **editing** your question, not putting it in comments. If you have a registered account (which you have), you should be able to [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

The select error that you are getting would be from this subquery in your original post:

```
SELECT V.PRICE + (V.PRICE * 0.1) FROM VENDOR V
WHERE V.ITEMNO=IT.ITEMNO
```

From what I gather, `ITEMNO` is a primary key in the `ITEMS` table, but it is a foreign key reference in the `VENDOR` table. The error indicates that the statement above it matching more than one entry in the `VENDOR` table as you have discovered from your last comment. Once that is fixed and the subquery no longer returns more than one row, your original query should work correctly. However, I would recommend considering a different approach to that as it will trigger a similar failure if the subquery ever returns no rows or more than one row. Without knowing more about what you are trying to achieve, I'm not sure what to recommend for that.